# ASP.NET Core 2.0 How to access UserManager in a policy?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have this requirement class that needs access to usermanager

```
public class NoAdminRequirment : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    bool NoAdmins { get; set; }
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;

    public NoAdminRequirment(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
            NoAdmins = userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("administrators").Result.Count() == 0;
    }
}
```

My understanding is that the usermanager is being initialized automatically by dependency injection since I have that set up in my application

Well this is not very usefull since I need to pass the usermanager in the policy now

```
services.AddAuthorization(option =>
{
    option.AddPolicy("NoAdmins", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new { /*???*/ }));
});
```

Can someone suggest an alternative or a way to access the usermanager?

Comment: Why do you need the usermanager for? You need to check if the current user satisfies the requirement, in your case if i understand correctly, not in a certain role

Comment: @Borka i need to check if ANY user has the role of admin.

Comment: the policies are used to determine if the current user(the one making the request) has the necessary permissions to access a certain resource. if your auth is done right you will get info about the user making the request and then determine if they are the right ones to access that method or controller. 
Read more about policy auth [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Oh ok. Can you suggest a way on how to check "if there's no user that has the role of admin" make the controller accessible? I know it's weird. But I'm trying to simplify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
public class ExcludeRoleRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
  public string Role { get; private set; }

  public ExcludeRoleRequirement(string role)
  {
    Role = role;
  }
}
```

Since `ExcludeRoleHandler` is registered to the DI container, and i'm assuming that the UserManager is registered too, you can add UserManager to the constructor

```
public class ExcludeRoleHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ExcludeRoleRequirement>
{
  private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _manager;
  public ExcludeRoleHandler(UserManager<IdentityUser> manager)
  {
    _manager = manager;
  }
  protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, 
    ExcludeRoleRequirement requirement)
  {
    var usersInRole = await _manager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(requirement.Role);
    if (!usersInRole.Any())
    {
      context.Succeed(requirement);
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
  }
}
```

Then in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthorization(option => {
  options.AddPolicy("NoAdmin", policy =>
    policy.Requirements.Add(new ExcludeRoleRequirement("administrators")));  
});


services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, ExcludeRoleHandler>();
```

Hope this helps

EDIT: I forgot to add

```
[Authorize(Policy = "NoAdmin")]
public class NotForAdminController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

Comment: Okay you might want to do that for future reference. Thanks it worked after minor adjustments.

Comment: Also, a few people have mention that this doesn't make sense. Makes me wonder if there's a better way to implement this..

Answer (score -1):

```
services.AddAuthorization(option => {
    option.AddPolicy("NoAdmins", policy => 
                policy.Requirements.Add(services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<NoAdminRequirment>()));
});
```

Comment: he would still need `AuthorizationHandler` i think